# C# How to read lines of large txt file without freezing the app

Tags: c#, freeze, txt

When i load lines of a large txt file the app freezing until the load is finished, i need to load those lines without freezing the entire app

i try this

`string lines[] = File.ReadLines(@"file.txt").ToArray();`

and also try this

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    string line;
    var lineNumber = 0;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Skip or [rocess each line here
        lineNumber++;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked into `ReadLineAsync`?

Comment: This is a difficult topic for a beginner. The magic is in threads, tasks and asynchronous programming. But if these terms don't tell you anything, you should familiarize youself with these concepts first.

Comment: Is this a console app, desktop app or web app?
When you say it freezes the entire app is that some gui that are not responsive?

Comment: i'm going to look on that, is desktop app

Comment: @merlider Your code should work for non heavy files (<1GiB). If the problem occurs for medium size files, the freezing may be due to your computer not having enough ressources to process it. What is your computer specs ?

Comment: im running on high pc specs, so the thing is the txt is up to 2gb, i'm thinking the best way is splitting the file

Comment: The problem may be when you try to open and load the file data into memory. There are more advanced and fancy ways to read a file bytes by bytes without loading everything into memory. Sadly, I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try async methods?

```
 static async Task ReadCharacters()
        {
            String result;
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("existingfile.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opened file.");
                result = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("First line contains: " + result);
            }
        }
```

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync?view=net-7.0][1]

Comment: how to read all or specific group of lines with this method, i try while ((result = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null) but still freezing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).